# Setting up Django app on Heroku via Cygwin giving permission denied error when installing pip

Tags: python, django, heroku, cygwin, pip

I'm trying to deploy a Django app on Heroku using http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django. I just so happen to use Windows, so I've been working via Cygwin (please don't judge me >< ). In short, everything is fine until I run "virtualenv venv --distribute". When I run this, regardless of where I run it, I get a permission denied error. Here's the output:

```
$ virtualenv venv --distribute
New python executable in venv/bin/python2.6
Not overwriting existing python script venv/bin/python.exe (you must use venv/bi
n/python2.6.exe)
Installing distribute...........................................................
................................................................................
...................................................done.
Installing pip...
  Error [Errno 13] Permission denied while executing command /cygdrive/c/Users/D
a...env/bin/easy_install /usr/lib/python2.6/s...pport/pip-1.1.tar.gz
...Installing pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.7.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.6.egg/virtualenv
.py", line 928, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.6.egg/virtualenv
.py", line 1042, in create_environment
    install_pip(py_executable, search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_dow
nload)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.6.egg/virtualenv
.py", line 640, in install_pip
    filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.6.egg/virtualenv
.py", line 966, in call_subprocess
    cwd=cwd, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Things I've already tried:

- run Cygwin as an administrator (the Windows-equivalent to sudo)
- chmod 777'ed EVERYTHING known to man
- banged my head against the wall

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think you'd be best to follow the instructions I've written here:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/

Once everything's working properly in a normal windows environment, they should also work properly in cygwin or msys.

Comment: This works properly on windows native (thank you for that!), so if I run via command line, it works, but unfortunately it doesn't affect the issue on Cygwin... the Cygwin issue still persists.